# setting viewmodel property to be an item from a list

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

ok so i have my view model

```
function viewModel(calendarData) {
            var self = this;

            self.Calendars = ko.mapping.fromJS(calendarData);
            self.ViewedCalendar = {};//what can/should i set this to be on initial creation?
            self.DisplayCalendar = function (calendar) {
                self.ViewedCalendar = calendar;
            };
        };
```

I then have my html:

```
<div data-bind="visible: Calendars().length > 0">
    <h2>You have <span data-bind="text: Calendars().length"></span> calendars</h2>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Calendars</th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: Calendars">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
                <td><span data-bind="text: Events().length"></span> events</td>
                <td><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.DisplayCalendar'>View</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div data-bind="visible: ViewedCalendar() !== null">
    Your are viewing <span data-bind="text: ViewedCalendar.Name"></span><br />
</div>
```

What I am trying to achieve is when the user clicks View for a given calendar, that via DisplayCalendar() I set the property ViewedCalendar to be set to the given calendar.

This then shows my div that contains the label stating what calendar is being viewed.

This is all rough code at the minute just to get the basic functionality in place but I'm new to knockout so could use some help.

I'm getting TypeError: ViewedCalendar is not a function or ViewedCalendar is undefined.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ViewedCalendar` property needs to be an observable for knockout to reach to changes in it's value. You defined it like this:

```
self.ViewedCalendar = {};
```

Which is an (empty) object literal and not a function (as the error message correctly stated). What you need is:

```
self.ViewedCalendar = ko.observable();    // empty () give you an empty observable - no calendar selected yet
```

And then you can update it in your `click` handler with:

```
self.ViewedCalendar(calendar);
```

Here's a working full example:

```js
function viewModel(calendarData) {
            var self = this;

            self.Calendars = ko.mapping.fromJS(calendarData);
            self.ViewedCalendar = ko.observable();
            self.DisplayCalendar = function (calendar) {
                self.ViewedCalendar(calendar);
            };
        };

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel([{Name:'some calendar', Events: []}, {Name:'another calendar', Events: []}]));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.js"></script>

<div data-bind="visible: Calendars().length > 0">
    <h2>You have <span data-bind="text: Calendars().length"></span> calendars</h2>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Calendars</th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: Calendars">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
                <td><span data-bind="text: Events().length"></span> events</td>
                <td><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.DisplayCalendar'>View</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div data-bind="with: ViewedCalendar">
    Your are viewing <span style="font-weight: bold" data-bind="text: Name"></span><br />
</div>
```

Comment: @Jeroen: If you have no objection, I'll stick your fiddle link into my answer. I just didn't have time to throw one together myself. I'll remove it if you feel it's bad form.